# ODBC SQL Server Driver Login timeout expired

Tags: sql-server, odbc, ssms, sql-server-express

I'm failing to connect to a SQL server SQLExpress. The connection worked fine a few days ago.
This is how I tried to connect (I'm using Microsoft SQL server management studio):

```
connection = pyodbc.connect("DSN=sqlServer; UID=myuser;PWD=mypassword") 
cursor = connection.cursor()
```

The error I get:

> ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

In the ODBC Data Source Administrator, when I test the data source I get:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I got the similar issue.

The problem was actually I was using "SQL Server" as the driver in my ODBC settings in my DSN.

The driver should be "SQL Server Native Client 11.0".

It fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Old question and answer but you saved my day. I had the same problem but... only from time to time! Once the connection failed, it was impossible to make it work again. I had to reboot the computer! :-(

Answer (score 4):

Because you are having the same issue in the ODBC Data Source Administrator I would try to focus on that first not on your code.

[Here you can find a list with possible problems](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190181(v=sql.105).aspx)

Maybe this can help you find out what the problem is.

I also would try to connect with the SQL Server Management Studio.
Maybe it is possible to connect with a different user or via Windows login. 
That would mean that your user might not exist anymore (maybe because you renewed tha database or something).

Also I sometimes have the problem that the SQL Server is not started either locally or on the server.
Maybe you could check if the service is started and the database is running.

Comment: connecting through SQL Server Management Studio is working fine with the username and password in my code. Checking in Sql Server Configuration Manager- "Sql Server (SQLEXPRESS)" in running

Comment: @user5435739 have you checked your configuration of your odbc source? And checked if your application can run with a 64 bit odbc source?

Comment: I can only say the connection worked before. How can I check the things you've mentioned?